# HAproxy: digest authentication

Tags: haproxy

We have setup a loadbalancer to balance 2 servers. The config looks like this:

> global
>       maxconn 40960
>       user haproxy
>       group haproxy
>       daemon
>
> defaults
>       log     global
>       option  dontlognull
>       retries 3
>       timeout client 10s
>       timeout server 10s
>       timeout connect 4s
>       maxconn 40960
>
> listen webpool lbIP:80
>       mode http
>       cookie SERVERID insert indirect
>       balance roundrobin
>       server slave1 slave1IP:80 cookie A check port 8981
>       server slave2 slave2IP:80 cookie B check port 8982

The servers slave1 and slave2 needs digest authentication. When the client sends a request the first request is balanced to slave1. This returns a 401: Unauthorized. The second request is balanced to slave2 and will succeed, it returns a 200: OK. The problem is that the authentication always happens on slave1 and the the response always came from slave2. I want both requests(authentication and returning data) into one connection/slave.

Is it possible to configure this in HAproxy?

Thanks John